# Build flex .... divider

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build the following table below. Having trouble building out the center ... divider between the key and the value. It should grow/shrink based on the column width. Any ideas on how I might achieve this with css?

[image]

Comment: You shoukd Add the code

Comment: are you thinking of justify-content:space-between?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is possible to work with a table:

```
<table class="tab">
  <tr>
    <td class="wordsleft">First Name:</td>
    <td class="distance"></td>
    <td class="wordsright">Guy</td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="wordsleft">Last Name:</td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="wordsright">Bronson</td></tr>
</table>
```

and the CSS:

```
.tab {
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
.tab tr {
  border-bottom:2px dotted black;
}
.tab .distance {
  width:50px;
}
.tab .wordsleft {
  border-bottom-style:none;
  text-align:left;
}
.tab .wordsright{
  border-bottom-style:none;
  text-align:right;
}
```

I hope it works